# ¿Cómo puedo escribir en excel el resultado de una suma con Python?

Tags: python

Intento sumar 2 números que se localizan en una hoja de excel y escribir el resultado en esa hoja de excel y obtengo el siguiente error:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/JMMA/Desktop/E.xlsx'

Sé que me está denegando el permiso pero no sé cómo solucionarlo.

```
    import openpyxl

def suma_y_escribe_resultado(nombre_archivo, celda_numero1, celda_numero2, celda_resultado):
    # Abre el archivo de Excel
    libro = openpyxl.load_workbook(nombre_archivo)

    # Selecciona la hoja activa
    hoja = libro.active

    # Obtiene los valores de las celdas
    numero1 = hoja[celda_numero1].value
    numero2 = hoja[celda_numero2].value

    # Verifica que ambos valores no sean None y que sean de tipo numérico
    if isinstance(numero1, (int, float)) and isinstance(numero2, (int, float)):
        # Realiza la suma
        resultado = numero1 + numero2

        # Escribe el resultado en la celda especificada
        hoja[celda_resultado] = resultado

        # Guarda los cambios en el archivo
        libro.save(nombre_archivo)
    else:
        print("Al menos uno de los valores en las celdas no es un número. Verifica tus datos.")

# Ejemplo de uso
archivo_excel = 'D:/JMMA/Desktop/E.xlsx'
celda_num1 = 'A1'
celda_num2 = 'B1'
celda_resultado = 'C1'

suma_y_escribe_resultado(archivo_excel, celda_num1, celda_num2, celda_resultado)
```

Comment: Parece que tu archivo excel esta abierto por otro proceso. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Abraham por responder. Sí, efectivamente, si cierro excel, el programa funciona pero me expliqué muy mal, lo siento. Lo que me gustaría es que se ejecutase el programa con el excel abierto, ¿es posible?

Comment: disculpen, no puedo agregar comentarios, pero si deseas tener el libro de excel abierto y hacer modificaciones porque no usas VBA para excel o es necesario hacerlo on python?. se me ocurre otra solución, ejecutar tu script python desde vba WScript.shell y el resultado obtenerlo en un archivo de texto y luego leerlo con VBA y pasarlo a una variable y enviarlo a la celda indicada. pero ya es un trabajo más extenso. es necesario tener el libro de excel abierto?
es necesario hacerlo desde python? cada uno tiene sus pro y contras jajaja. Saludos.

Comment: Querés hacer una modificación al archivo y que se vea "en tiempo real" en el excel? Si es así, no vas a poder hacerlo con openpyxl. Tal vez usando VBA como indica el compañero, o con la api de windows, sea posible.

Comment: sorry pero mi ultima modificación no se aplicó, intentaste tener el libro de excel en modo compartido?, así ya puedes modificar y ver los cambios como si fuera otra persona. Saludos.

Comment: Usando OpenPyXL si se puede modificar un archivo .xslx cargando el archivo, abriendo la página (Sheet) y ubicando las celdas para modificar los datos, ejemplo : hoja.cell(row=index,column=2).value = "nuevo dato"

Answer (score -1):

El error

> PermissionError: [Errno 13]

en Python puede indicar que **el archivo no existe, o la ruta es incorrecta.**

Noto que tratas de abrir el archivo de esta forma:

```
 libro = openpyxl.load_workbook('D:/JMMA/Desktop/E.xlsx')
```

si es así, debes asegurarte que el archivo existe y existe en la ruta indicada (`D:/JMMA/Desktop/`)

---

Si el archivo se encuentra en el working directory de python puedes abrirlo de esta forma, indicando el nombre del archivo

```
libro = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'E.xlsx')
```

y guardarlo de la misma forma con el nombre del archivo:

```
libro.save('E.xlsx')
```

Revisa la [documentación de OpenPyXL](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html)